# Healthy recipes has stopped working

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a completed android app program in eclipse Juno(windows 8.1), when i try to run it on the nexus one emulator with my target API at 20 it crashes. The minimum API is set at 14 for my project, and I have zero errors showing in my windows.

I do get this text "Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched..." after the android screen on the emulator goes away and a background appears with the time.

I have used the Android Boot Camp book as a reference and followed the AVD set-up to the letter.

this is my mainactivity.java code, Recipe.java code follows it. logcat error list from crash follows

```
package net.androidbootcamp.healthyrecipes;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRecipe);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Recipe.class));
        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}


package net.androidbootcamp.healthyrecipes;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Recipe extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.recipe);
    }
}
```

```
09-07 03:18:01.230: E/AndroidRuntime(665): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-07 03:18:01.230: E/AndroidRuntime(665): Process: net.androidbootcamp.healthyrecipes, PID: 665
09-07 03:18:01.230: E/AndroidRuntime(665): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.androidbootcamp.healthyrecipes/net.androidbootcamp.healthyrecipes.MainActivity}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine swipe dismissal and the action bar.
09-07 03:18:01.230: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2197)
09-07 03:18:01.230: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2258)
09-07 03:18:01.230: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
09-07 03:18:01.230: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1209)
09-07 03:18:01.230: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-07 03:18:01.230: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
09-07 03:18:01.230: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5026)
09-07 03:18:01.230: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-07 03:18:01.230: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-07 03:18:01.230: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
09-07 03:18:01.230: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
09-07 03:18:01.230: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-07 03:18:01.230: E/AndroidRuntime(665): Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine swipe dismissal and the action bar.
09-07 03:18:01.230: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:275)
09-07 03:18:01.230: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2872)
09-07 03:18:01.230: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3129)
09-07 03:18:01.230: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:303)
09-07 03:18:01.230: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1930)
09-07 03:18:01.230: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at net.androidbootcamp.healthyrecipes.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
09-07 03:18:01.230: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5242)
09-07 03:18:01.230: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
09-07 03:18:01.230: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2161)
09-07 03:18:01.230: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: What does logcat say?

Comment: once the app crashes the first error is "FATAL EXCEPTION:main"

Comment: I would add the stack trace to your answer to make it a bit easier to help you

Comment: Please post the whole stacktrace.

Comment: I dont know how to do that..

Comment: Learn about your logcat. Most likely, you'll be able to fix this issue yourself once you do. Or learn how to copy/paste. That would be swell, too!

Comment: I'm asking for help as i don't have the time to learn about my logcat. this project is due tomorrow and this is the last step. also added the logcat errors

Comment: Sorry, this isn't the forum for homework help... but if you only *read* the logcat, you would have your answer. So sad.

Comment: the project is completed, meaning i don't need homework help. I'm having a problem running an emulator. I have ZERO prior experience in coding. ZERO experience in reading/ understanding logcat and I'm taking classes for it. I have to start somewhere. I'm asking for help because I just don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

Do not target API Level of 20 and Platform 4.4W (which is Android Wear SDK) as Android Virtual Device.

Use API level 19 and everything should work fine.

In your manifest (AndroidManifest.xml)

```
    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

Comment: is there an easy way to change that without starting over? I'm completly new to the program.

Comment: This is an easy change, just edit (ONLY) the AndroidManifest.xml file, no need to start over.

Comment: i only saw the text first